# Receiving an InterfaeError 0 in Python using mysqldb

Tags: python, mysql-python

I'm getting an InterfaceError: (0,'') when trying to execute a query in some python code.  I'll post the code I'm using below.

```
 def insert_into_table(schema, table, connection, filename = 'pathToAnInputFile'):
        x = connection.cursor()
        with open(filename, 'rb') as csvfile:
            reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"')
            next(reader)
            for line in reader:
                query = "INSERT INTO {0}.{1} (field1, field2, field3) VALUES ('{2}', '{3}', '{4}')".format(table, schema, line[0], line[1], line[2])
                print query
                x.execute(query)
                conn.commit()

        conn.close()

import MySQLdb
import csv as csv
conn = MySQLdb.connect("localhost", "nottheusername", "notthepassword", db="adb") 

insert_into_table('atablename', 'adb', conn)
```

And here is the output I'm getting

> INSERT INTO adb.atablename (field1, field2, field3) VALUES ('dogs',
>   'puppies', 'Nov 21, 2017')
>       ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
>       InterfaceError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
>        in ()
>       ----> 1 insert_into_table('atablename', 'adb', conn)
>
> ```
> <ipython-input-24-02df4bf9bbdb> in insert_into_table(schema, table, connection, filename)
>       8             query = "INSERT INTO {0}.{1} (RMS_CLASS_NM, campaign, ad_group) VALUES ('{2}', '{3}', '{4}')".format(table,
> ```
>
> schema, line[0], line[1], line[2])
>             9             print query
>       ---> 10             x.execute(query)
>            11             conn.commit()
>            12
>
> ```
> C:\Users\braddavi\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\cursors.pyc
> ```
>
> in execute(self, query, args)
>           224         except Exception:
>           225             exc, value = sys.exc_info()[:2]
>       --> 226             self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)
>           227         self._executed = query
>           228         if not self._defer_warnings: self._warning_check()
>
> ```
> C:\Users\braddavi\AppData\Local\Continuum\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\MySQLdb\connections.pyc
> ```
>
> in defaulterrorhandler(***failed resolving arguments***)
>            34     del connection
>            35     if isinstance(errorvalue, BaseException):
>       ---> 36         raise errorvalue
>            37     if errorclass is not None:
>            38         raise errorclass(errorvalue)
>
> ```
> InterfaceError: (0, '')
> ```

I've done some searching for information on this particular error, and it seems as though it is typically associated with having a global cursor being created rather than a local cursor being created within the function that is using it, but that's not the problem in this case- or at least if it is, it isn't obvious to me.

I should also point out that if I take the query printed out from the print query line and execute it directly in a mysqldb terminal it executes and inserts the data without any difficulty.

If anyone can help, it would be greatly appreciated.

Happy holidays to all.
Brad

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this should qualify as a full answer, but I found a solution.  Instead of opening the using csv.reader inside the same function that I'm trying to push the data into the table with, I broke it down into two separate functions.  The first one reads the CSV file and stores each line as a list, and then stores all the lists as a list of lists.  That list of lists is then passed on to a different routine to insert the data into the table.  I don't know why this would solve the problem, unless it's some weird incompatiblility with csv reader and mysqldb.  Either way, if someone runs into this problem, this is a solution that may work for you.